Calculating homology of Hirzecruch surfaces
Let $\mathbb{F}_{n}=\mathbb{P}(O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(n)\oplus\mathbb{C})$ be the Hirzebruch surface. Suppose $E_{0}$ is the zero-section, and $C$ is a fiber. How to show that $H_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{n},\mathbb{Z})$ is spanned by $E_{0}$ and $C$?
In p518 of Griffiths-Harris, it says $\mathbb{F}_{n}-E_{0}-C$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-bundle over $\mathbb{C}$, and therefore is contractible. Hence
$$H_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{n},\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{2}(E_{0}\cup C,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}\{E_{0},C\}.$$
Maybe we can use the MV sequence to get this, but I don't know how to choose the open covering. If I take $U=\mathbb{F}_{n}-E_{0}-C$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $E_{0}\cup C$, then how can I calculate the homology of $U\cap V$?

Let $P$ be the intersection point of $E_0$ and $C$. Then
$$
\mathbb{F}_n = 
\{P\} \cup (E_0 \setminus P) \cup (C \setminus P) \cup U
$$
is a cellular decomposition with cells of dimensions $(0,2,2,4)$, hence the differentials in the cell complex are zero, and it follows that the closures of the 2-cells give a basis in $H_2$.
